# Let $f,g$ be continuous such that $\int^b_a{f(x)dx} = \int^b_a{g(x)dx}$. Show that there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous such that $\int^b_a{f(x)dx} = \int^b_a{g(x)dx}$. Show that there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$

is the idea that using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: there exists some $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $\int^b_a{f(x_o)dx} = f(b) - f(a)= g(b) - g(a) = \int^b_a{g(x_0)dx}$?

Comment: You want the Integral Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: That is not quite the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. It is the anti-derivative

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** We then have
$$
\int_a^b(f(x)-g(x))=0.
$$
If $h(x):=f(x)-g(x)$ never equals $0$ on $[a,b]$, then, as it is a continuous function, it must be either always positive or always negative on that interval. But could its integral be $0$, then?

Comment: One could also just appeal to Rolle's theorem...

Comment: i'm following so far, how do we use $x_0$ to show that this is a point in which the integral is $0$?

Comment: @Jayant.M What do you mean? You want to show that such an $x_0$ exists. What I propose is to show that the non-existence of such an $x_0$ would lead to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be an anti derivative of $f$. By the mean value theorem, there exists some $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that 
$$
F'(\xi) = \frac{F(b) - F(a)}{b-a}.
$$
In integral form, this is 
$$
f(\xi) = \frac{\int_a^b f(x) \, dx}{b-a}.
$$
Now as @Guest suggests, replace $f$ in the above by $h = f - g$, with $f,g$ as in the original post.